# /var/log/nginx/error.log Показывает ошибку No such file or directory, хотя файл существует 100%.Flask + uWSGI

Tags: linux, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Коллеги я впервые разворачивал uwsgi делал все по инструкции отсюда - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru
И при обычном запуске uwsgi --socket ip:port --protocol=http -w wsgi:MYAPP
Все отлично запускается.
создал файл myapp.ini со следующим содержанием:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:myapp

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

все как в инструкции.
Далее создал файл .service со следующим содержанием:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve MYAPP
After=network.target

[Service]
User=USERNAME
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/USER/projects/MYAPP
Environment="PATH=/home/USER/projects/MYAPP/.venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/USER/projects/MYAPP/.venv/bin/uwsgi --ini     myapp.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

далее
sudo systemctl start myproject
sudo systemctl enable myproject
sudo systemctl status myproject - там все окей работает сервис

Далее настройка nginx
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
и в нем

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name Мой домен www.мой домен;

       location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/USER/projects/MYAPP/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

файл mayapp.sock - существует 100% он в папке там же где и файл ini от uwsgi.
сделал рестарт  nginx, опять же по инструкции, проверил на ошибки nginx -t - все окей.

НО в less /var/log/nginx/error.log ошибка:
*1 connect() to unix:/home/USER/projects/MYAPP/myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
Но файл на месте железобетонно. помогите решить проблему, не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь как проект называется — APP MYAPP или вообще без подпапки

Comment: @andreymal Да согласен немного смутил этими неточностями. Поправил все но не в этом дело было.